Branches out of sync because of git cherry pick - how to resync
So I started working on a project with two branches-

master

stage.


The strategy has been to cherry-pick commits from stage to master and multiple teams do the same everyday.
Now this has caused master and stage to be totally out of sync with a difference of 30,000+ commits (since cherry-pick creates a new sha for every commit). If we try to sync the branches, these are shown as conflicts and new files.
While both the branches more or less have the same code, is there any solution to the below-

Tell GIT that the two branches are the same now and to ignore the past differences? This way, we can start merging feature branches into stage and master instead of doing cherry-picks.

Somehow sync the two branches without recreating them?

Point both the branches to the same HEAD so that the branches are now considered the same?

Any alternate strategy to fix this mess?


Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

You could merge one onto the other and ask git to not bring in any changes... something like:
git checkout master
git merge -s ours stage -m "Merging stage branch _but_ discarding any changes"

master would have the same content before and after the merge so no effective change.
So, now, you can continue merging stage into master knowing that it will only consider changes that were introduced in stage past this point.
You could also consider doing the same thing later in the opposite direction if you intend to merge them in both directions.
